# Is there something similar to `delete-other-windows` (`C-x 1`), but that allows me to restore my window arrangement

Tags: emacs, window

Suppose I have a buffer that's a bit too cramped in its current window, so I decide I want to briefly give it more space, then go back to what I was doing. Is it possible for me to just temporarily *hide* other windows instead of deleting them like `C-x 1` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your init file:

```
(winner-mode 1)
```

Then you can use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> as normal, and afterwards use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> to call `winner-undo` to restore the previous window configuration.

You can use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> repeatedly to step back through previous configurations, and <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><right></kbd> to jump back to the latest one again.

n.b. This is a general-purpose feature that is incredibly useful in all kinds of situations besides this specific example.  I highly recommend getting familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the window configuration to a register, go to a single window and when you are done, restore the window configuration from the register:

- Save the window configuration to register `z`: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>
- Go to a single window: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> and do what you need to do (but do not disturb register `z`!)
- Restore the window configuration from register `z`: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>

Do `(info "(elisp)Registers")` for information on [registers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Registers.html#Registers). Do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>window-configuration-to-register</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> for information on the function that is bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Library [`frame-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-cmds.el) has commands for this. They are essentially repeatable versions of standard Emacs commands, such as `enlarge-window`.

By *"repeatable"* I mean that you can just repeat the last keystroke of a key sequence.

For example, by default `C-x }` is bound to the standard Emacs command `enlarge-window-horizontally`.  To repeat it you need to repeat the whole key sequence each time: `C-x } C-x } C-x } ...`.  (Or else you need to provide a numeric prefix arg for the number of columns you want to enlarge the window.)

But the repeatable version, command `enlarge-window-horizontally-repeat` lets you do just `C-x } } } ...`.

The definitions are simple.  They use this helper function:

```lisp
(defun repeat-command (command)
  "Repeat COMMAND."
  (require 'repeat)         ; Define its vars before we let-bind them.
  (let ((repeat-previous-repeated-command  command)
        (repeat-message-function           #'ignore)
        (last-repeatable-command           'repeat))
    (repeat nil)))
```

This is all there is to the definition of `enlarge-window-horizontally-repeat`:

```lisp
(defun enlarge-window-horizontally-repeat ()
  "Enlarge selected window horizontally by one column.
You can repeat this by hitting the last key again..."
  (interactive)
  (require 'repeat)
  (frcmds-repeat-command 'enlarge-window-horizontally))
```

Here are some key bindings you might use:

```lisp
(global-set-key [remap enlarge-window-horizontally] 'enlarge-window-horizontally-repeat)
(global-set-key [remap shrink-window-horizontally]  'shrink-window-horizontally-repeat)
(global-set-key [remap enlarge-window]              'enlarge/shrink-window-repeat)
```

---

Besides this, there is also standard Emacs command `shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer`, bound by default to `C-x -`.  It shrinks the window to fit your buffer content.

Comment: @picklerick: I'm well aware of `set-transient-map` (which is not "modern"). Using `repeat` does not replace all uses of `set-transient-map`, but it is simple (and `repeat` itself uses `set-transient-map`). `repeat` has additional the advantage that it's usable with Emacs back through Emacs 22. But please feel free to add another answer, which uses `set-transient-map` directly.

Comment: oh, thanks, I didn't realize it used `set-transient-map`, but of course that makes sense :)